# Upgrade a cordless screwdriver (16.8 V) to Li-Poly

Tags: batteries, current, motor, dc-motor, lithium

I'd like to upgrade my cordless screwdriver/drill to use lithium polymer batteries. Problem is, the screwdriver uses 16.8 V at the moment (14 NiMh 1.2 V cells).

So, using lithium polymer batteries with 3.7 V each, I have the choice between 4 cells (14.8 V) or 5 cells (18.5 V).

14.8 V would be an expensive downgrade - especially for the drilling. I am not even sure if this would work (but probably it would, right... I am not experienced with these things).

18.5 V on the other hand would be a difference of 1.6 V or a bit more than 10 %. Would the motor survive that?

Suggestions on how to do this upgrade are most appreciated!

Comment: downvote without explanation... come on...

Comment: This is almost impossible to do - you will need a new charging circuit and you'll need a controller that monitors the battery state. Miss any of these and you have a battery explosion. When you start evaluating the amount of effort need to do this properly you'll see that it's much wiser to just buy an off-the-shelf new one.

Comment: I wanted to go with these instructions:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Converting-Cordless-To-Lithium-Li-Po/step5/Enjoy-The-Power-Of-Lithium/
But maybe you are still right.

Comment: Well, that manual shows clear lack of knowledge of difference between the NiMH and the LiIon batteries. The latter are well... more delicate, for example, they are much more sensitive to overheating. You may succeed in doing that for some low power application but certainly not for a power tool.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it. The fully charged Li-Ion battery is 4.2V so, in my opinion, even 4 batteries pack will do the job. And it is not downgrade actually, because you get higher capacity with lower weight.

But if you want to use 5 batteries pack - do it. Even 21V will not harm your drill.

The only problem with this upgrade is with the recharging. Usually, the NiMH batteries have external charger, that charges them with constant current.

Li-Ion batteries on the other hand use much more complex charging algorithm and are very prone to over-discharge and over-charge.

So, you will need special charger. You can build one by yourself, using the available chips that implements the whole charging algorithm.

Easier solution is to design your battery holder for standard type of batteries, like 18650 or 16340 (smaller) (it depends of what capacity you want to have), replace them when discharged and charge in the stand-alone charger for this type of cells.

These cells are produced with internal protection ([for example this type](http://dx.com/p/trustfire-3-7v-3200mah-li-ion-18650-batteries-red-black-golden-2-pcs-247839)) so it is hard to discharge it too much.

Here is an [example for suitable charger.](http://dx.com/p/lightmore-q-128-power-adapter-charger-for-18650-26650-16340-aa-aaa-battery-black-eu-plug-152499)

Comment: thank you! This is a great answer. Concerning the charging, I would go with the solution offered in these instructions: http://www.instructables.com/id/Converting-Cordless-To-Lithium-Li-Po/step5/Enjoy-The-Power-Of-Lithium/. However, you state quite the opposite of @sharptooth above. What do you think about his objections?

Comment: @Marcel - IMO, sharptooth's opjections are pointless. Everything, not in conflict with the fundamental nature laws, can be done. And if you want to prove that something is not possible, some reference to a broken law is mandatory. :)

Comment: @johnfound: How about the following nature law: *if you discharge a Li-Ion battery too fast it gets overheated and can explode*?

Comment: @sharptooth - Sorry, it is not a nature law. Almost everything can "explode" if heated fast enough. But this will not stop you to use a glass bottles for example. Also, read the links I provided. The modern Li-Ion batteries have built-in protection that will not allow such modes of operation.

Comment: @johnfound: That page states *Over-discharging Protection* which typically means the battery will not allow to discharge it too deep.

Comment: @sharptooth - also it states: Buitl-in Protected Circuit Yes; Over Voltage Protection Yes; Short-circuit Protection Yes; Over-charging Protection Yes; Over-discharging Protection Yes; And typical 18650 cell can provide much more current than this drill can consume.

Comment: @johnfound: Unless it explicitly says "overheat protection" this doesn't disprove my statement.

Comment: @sharptooth - your Li-phobia argues here, not you. Li-Ion cells does not explode like TNT. :)